# What happens to an abandoned army of the undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, necromancy, villain

I had two high-level necromancers summon close to an army of undead and now they have left the area and not re-asserted control. I know a lot if not all of the undead will wander now but how many could just fall apart dead? Is there any tables or random explanations for this?

Comment: Related, suggested as duplicate: [What happens if you don't recast Animate Dead within 24 hours](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47722/23547)

Comment: The important thing we need to know to answer this is how the undead were created. Different spells and powers likely have different rules, and if you just handwaved how they were created maybe there isn't a rules answer. You could specify which powers were used to create the army, or maybe ask for lore on historical events which include abandoned undead armies.

Comment: For those voting to reopen - do you feel it's clear as to how the undead were created? Or do you feel like it's not necessary to not know that in order to answer the question? It seems like we need to understand the mechanic to be able to say with authority what happens.

Comment: I voted to reopen. I feel to close a question as unclear, one should know at least two conflicting options of answering it. Only then should one keep less informed others from answering it via close-vote. Having a vague feeling it might be unclear, or not having enough information for your own answer is not enough for me. Despite lengthy comment threads, I see not a single hint at a possibly conflicting answer to the one given. Even with the wild speculations not backed by the question text, the existing answer would still be correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### They are going to stick around

[Animate Dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead), [Create Undead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-undead) and [Finger of Death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death) are likely means for necromancers to do this, and are spells with an instant duration.
The *Sage Advice Compendium* tells us:

> For example, the instantaneous spell *animate dead* harnesses magical energy to turn a corpse or a pile of bones into an undead creature. That necromantic magic is present for an instant and is then gone. The resulting undead now exists without the magic’s help.

The only time limit is on when your control expires, as per the spell description (same for both *animate dead* and *create undead*; *finger* does not have such a limitation, so the problem would not arise):

> The creature is under your control for 24 hours, after which it stops obeying any command you've given it.

So those undead are not going to just fall apart they are going to stick around and do what undead do. Of course, it is your liberty as a DM to rule otherwise, to decide that they just stand around listlessly, or to create some behind-the-scenes activity where the military or city guard deal with them, and ask the local clergy to cast divination spells to figure out who is to blame for it if you are kind; you could also let them do horrible things and show the players that their actions have consequences that way.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149429/discussion-on-answer-by-nobody-the-hobgoblin-what-happens-to-an-abandoned-army-o); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.